# capture row count for database level audit action(DELETE, INSERT,UPDATE) in sql audit

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

While creating a SQL Audit in SQL Server 2008R2, how to configure the database level audit action group (eg.DELETE, INSERT,UPDATE) to capture the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can not track this in the audit log using SQL Server 2008 r2 sys.fn_get_audit_file returns all the values tracked in the audit and number of rows affected are not included in that list of items.

IN SQL Server 2012 you could do this using sp_audit_write and a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ChangeMonitor] ON [dbo].[TableToTrack]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
DECLARE
     @InsertCount INT
    ,@DeleteCount INT
    ,@msg NVARCHAR(4000)    

select  @DeleteCount = COUNT(*)
from deleted d

select @InsertCount = COUNT(*)
from inserted i

IF @InsertCount = @DeleteCount
BEGIN
    SET @msg = @InsertCount +' Records Updated'
    EXEC sp_audit_write @user_defined_event_id =  27 ,
              @succeeded =  1
            , @user_defined_information = @msg;
END

IF @InsertCount > @DeleteCount
BEGIN
    SET @msg = @InsertCount +' Records Inserted'
    EXEC sp_audit_write @user_defined_event_id =  27 ,
              @succeeded =  1
            , @user_defined_information = @msg;
END

IF @DeleteCount > @InsertCount
BEGIN
    SET @msg = @DeleteCount +' Records Deleted'
    EXEC sp_audit_write @user_defined_event_id =  27 ,
              @succeeded =  1
            , @user_defined_information = @msg;
END
GO
```

With some modification a trigger could still be used in SQL Server 2008 r2 to track the number of rows affected you just would not be able to use the audit log you could create your own log table and write the information that you want to that log table.

Through the trigger you have access to two temporary table inserted and deleted the table structure for these two tables is identical to the source table. Inserted contains all the new records that were inserted and deleted contains any records that were deleted. The tables are cleared after the event so its not something you can interact with outside the event that caused the trigger.

Using EVENTDATA() in the trigger you could get information about what triggered the event.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ChangeMonitor] ON [dbo].[TableToTrack]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
DECLARE
     @InsertCount INT
    ,@DeleteCount INT
    ,@msg NVARCHAR(4000)
    ,@data XML
    ,@PostTime DATETIME 
    ,@User NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@EventType NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@TSQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @data = EVENTDATA();

SET @PostTime = GETDATE() 
SET @User = CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER) 
SET @EventType = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
SET @TSQL = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)')   

select  @DeleteCount = COUNT(*)
from deleted d

select @InsertCount = COUNT(*)
from inserted i

IF @InsertCount = @DeleteCount
BEGIN
    -- SQL for logging updates
END

IF @InsertCount > @DeleteCount
BEGIN
    -- SQL for logging inserts 
END

IF @DeleteCount > @InsertCount
BEGIN
    -- SQL for loggin deletes
END
GO
```